# can not resolve 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to import Fresco library into my project ,so I add the following line to the dependencies section of my build.gradle file:

compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+'

and then I build the project , but It failed with "`Could not resolve <br>com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+.`":

[image: Error Info]

My development environment: 
IDE Android Studio 1.2.1.1
OS: Ubuntu 15.04(64 bits)

Comment: That looks like a typo in their instructions. Try `0.7.0` or `0.7.+`.

Comment: @CommonsWare It didn't make any difference.  Fresco: https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Comment: I added fresco to my project yesterday with the exact same compile directive and it worked just fine. You aren't in china are you? https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/568

Comment: Yes,I am in China... you mean the GFW?

Comment: Yes maven and jcenter are hard to get to from china. It is a known issue for fresco.

Comment: oh,I got it.Thank you ,I guess that I should use a vpn..

Comment: @ColinGillespie Now I have got a vpn,and I can visit any website I want,but it still not working,any suggestions?

Comment: @ColinGillespie Gilespie  I fixed it!!!! It's not caused by GFW .It works well when I replaced OpenJDK with Oracle-JDK on my ubuntu!

Comment: @MummyDing That's great to hear. Interesting though, I had no trouble using OpenJDK 1.8 on Fedora

Comment: @ColinGillespie My OpenJDK version is 1.7

Answer (score 3):

You just remove the + symbol from your dependencies...

```
 compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ... My issue caused by GFW... [I am Chinese cry :(]

Comment: @MummyDing Okay okay. I am indian Hahahahaha :)

Comment: oh.. Now I  have got a vpn,but it still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I fixed it!!!! It's not caused by GFW .It works well when I replaced OpenJDK with Oracle-JDK on my ubuntu!